# How do I retrieve data that has been selected and displayed on a different screen from Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, android-jetpack-compose

I have a problem when I want to display the list of data that I have selected from **EachRowSelectCustomer** in the **SelectCustomerScreen.kt** file so that it can be displayed to the **AddPeminjamanScreen** page on the Text() component. when I select one of the customers, the logcat result on "SharedViewModel" successfully captures it but not with AddPeminjamanScreen which only displays "null" in logcat. If there is indeed code that needs to be changed, help solve the problem I am experiencing, here's what the code looks like:

**File SharedViewModel.kt :**

```
@HiltViewModel
class SharedViewModel @Inject constructor() : ViewModel() {

    private val _selectedCustomer: MutableStateFlow<CustomerModel?> = MutableStateFlow(null)
    val selectedCustomer: StateFlow<CustomerModel?> = _selectedCustomer.asStateFlow()

    fun setSelectedCustomer(customer: CustomerModel) {
        _selectedCustomer.value = customer
        Log.d("SharedViewModel", "Selected customer changed: ${customer.item?.namaCustomer}")
        Log.d("SharedViewModel", "Customer key: ${customer.key}")
    }
}
```

**File AppNavigation.kt :**

```
            // Fragment AddPeminjamanScreen
            composable(
                route = Screens.AddPeminjamanScreen.name
            ) {
                val sharedViewModel: SharedViewModel = hiltViewModel()
                AddPeminjamanScreen(navController, sharedViewModel)
            }


            // Fragment SelectCustomerScreen
            composable(
                route = Screens.SelectCustomerScreen.name
            ) {
                val viewModel: CustomerViewModel = hiltViewModel()
                val sharedViewModel: SharedViewModel = hiltViewModel()

                SelectCustomerScreen(
                    navController = navController,
                    viewModel = viewModel,
                    sharedViewModel = sharedViewModel
                )
            }
```

**File SelectCustomerScreen.kt :**

```
@Composable
fun SelectCustomerScreen(
    navController: NavHostController,
    viewModel: CustomerViewModel = hiltViewModel(),
    sharedViewModel: SharedViewModel = hiltViewModel()
) {
           LazyColumn { items ->
                    EachRowSelectCustomer(
                        navController = navController,
                        itemState = items,
                        sharedViewModel = sharedViewModel
                    )
        }
    }
}

fun EachRowSelectCustomer(
    navController: NavHostController,
    itemState: CustomerModel,
    sharedViewModel: SharedViewModel
) {
    Column {
        Row(
            modifier = Modifier
                .clickable(
                    interactionSource = remember { MutableInteractionSource() },
                    indication = rememberRipple(bounded = true)
                ) {
                    // Customer set selected in SharedViewModel
                    sharedViewModel.setSelectedCustomer(itemState)

                    // Navigate to AddPeminjamanScreen
                    navController.navigateUp()
                }
        ) {
            Row{
                Text(
                    text = itemState.item?.namaCustomer!!
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**File AddPeminjamanScreen.kt :**

```
@Composable
fun AddPeminjamanScreen(
    navController: NavHostController,
    sharedViewModel: SharedViewModel = hiltViewModel()
) {

    val selectedCustomer by sharedViewModel.selectedCustomer.collectAsState()

    Log.d("AddPeminjamanScreen", "Selected Customer: $selectedCustomer")

        // ROW CUSTOMER
        Row(
            modifier = Modifier
                .clickable(
                    interactionSource = remember { MutableInteractionSource() },
                    indication = rememberRipple(bounded = true)
                ) {
                    navController.navigate(Screens.SelectCustomerScreen.name)
                }
        ) {
                // Display the name of the selected customer
                Text(
                    text = selectedCustomer?.item?.namaCustomer ?: "Select"
                )
    }
}
```

Comment: If you encounter problems, it's best to create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) when posting a question. You posted more than **300** (three hundred) lines of code for this issue. That's a lot for people to parse and try to debug online. Please edit your question and isolate the problem, in that way, you increase your chances of being helped. Please take a moment and read [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Thanks for your advice! I have updated my question by using MCVE. I hope this makes my problem easier to understand. If you have time, please take a look back and let me know if there is anything else that needs improvement. Thank you very much! @AlexMamo

Answer (score 0):

Your code's indentation is annoyingly ugly, i'm not judging but please reformat your code before you put it here, have some manner.

Why this function have 3 curly brackets at the end?

```kotlin
@Composable
fun SelectCustomerScreen(
    navController: NavHostController,
    viewModel: CustomerViewModel = hiltViewModel(),
    sharedViewModel: SharedViewModel = hiltViewModel()
) {
           LazyColumn { items ->
                    EachRowSelectCustomer(
                        navController = navController,
                        itemState = items,
                        sharedViewModel = sharedViewModel
                    )
        }
    }
}
```

How ever, here is something you can try:

1. You'd better not pass the ViewModel to another composable scope; instead, pass the state. A ViewModel is a (kind of) abstract representation of the screen state, and it doesn't make sense to pass it to another screen unless you are trying to reproduce the entire screen. However, if you need another screen to use that ViewModel, you should declare the sharedViewModel outside of the composable scope, like this: val sharedViewModel: SharedViewModel = hiltViewModel().

   ````kotlin
           composable(
               route = Screens.AddPeminjamanScreen.name
           ) {
               // this viewmodel is only available on this scope
               // put this to the global scope if you need to share this to another scope.
               val sharedViewModel: SharedViewModel = hiltViewModel()
               AddPeminjamanScreen(navController, sharedViewModel)
           }


           // Fragment SelectCustomerScreen
           composable(
               route = Screens.SelectCustomerScreen.name
           ) {
               val viewModel: CustomerViewModel = hiltViewModel()
               // you are not using shared viewmodel, instead - you are creating a new one. this new instance of view model won't recognize you previous screen saved state.
               val sharedViewModel: SharedViewModel = hiltViewModel()

               SelectCustomerScreen(
                   navController = navController,
                   viewModel = viewModel,
                   sharedViewModel = sharedViewModel
               )
           }
   ```
   ````
2. Use coroutine scope to emit new state for the MutableStateFlow.

   ```kotlin
   viewmodelScope.launch {
     state.emit(newState)
   }
   ```
3. I don't understand what you are trying to do with the `LazyColumn` neither where you got the `items` from - on the `LazyColumn`.
4. Addition: You might want to learn more about function scope.